# How to prevent raw_input from blocking on windows?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, python-multithreading, raw-input

I'm trying to build a basic chat application and I need it to post messages from other users while waiting for input from the client.

Of course `select()` is not an option on Windows for this case.

What else can I do?

I tried this, but the program still waits for input and then shows other messages:

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('10.0.0.11',1340))
def sender():
    while (True):
        try:
            s.send(raw_input(">> "))
        except:
            return
def geter():
    while(True):
        print s.recv(1000)
Thread(target=sender).start()
Thread(target=geter).start()
```

Comment: If you want to split the console into two panes, one scrolling view for displaying messages as they arrive and one for use input, then you can't use standard I/O with a cooked read. There are versions of curses console/terminal UI library available for Python on Windows, which may help to implement something like this in a cross-platform way, or you can use a GUI instead of a console/terminal interface.